# Amazon Linux での最新の OpenJDK へのアップデートについて

Tags: java, linux, aws, yum

Amazon Linux でOpenJDK 8 (1.8)を利用しているのですが、
Javaの脆弱性対応で最新の OpenJDK にアップデートしようと考えています。

ですが、Java SE 8 Update 141 が存在せずアップデートできません。

Java SE 7 Update 141は存在します。

確認した環境は下記の通りです。

Amazon Linux の yum リポジトリに最新の OpenJDK が更新されるのには
時間がかかるものでしょうか？

## Amazon Linux のバージョン

- Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09

## 有効にしている yum リポジトリ

- amzn-main
- amzn-updates

## 確認コマンド

$ yum check-update | grep java

java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64            1:1.7.0.141-2.6.10.1.73.amzn1  amzn-updates

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: java version "1.8.0_131" はインストール済みで、パッチが当たったVersion : 1.8.0.141 にアップデートできなくて悩んでおります。

Answer (score 1):

バージョンごとに別のパッケージになってます。1.8.0のパッケージをインストールしてみて下さい。

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

その後、2つのJavaがインストールされた状態になるので、alternatives でどちらを標準にするか選択します。

```
$ sudo alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
 + 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
*  2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

1.7.0が不要であれば削除して下さい。

```
$ sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

---

質問を理解できてませんでした。

`yum info java-1.8.0-openjdk` で更新の有無を確認できます。いま見ると、1.8.0.141 が公開されてるようです。 `sudo yum update java-1.8.0-openjdk` コマンドで更新出来ると思います。

```
$ yum info java-1.8.0-openjdk
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-updates/latest/primary_db                                                               | 436 kB     00:00
Installed Packages
Name        : java-1.8.0-openjdk
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.8.0.131
Release     : 2.b11.30.amzn1
Size        : 466 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : amzn-updates
Summary     : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
URL         : http://openjdk.java.net/
License     : ASL 1.1 and ASL 2.0 and GPL+ and GPLv2 and GPLv2 with exceptions and LGPL+ and LGPLv2 and MPLv1.0 and
            : MPLv1.1 and Public Domain and W3C
Description : The OpenJDK runtime environment.

Available Packages
Name        : java-1.8.0-openjdk
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.8.0.141
Release     : 1.b16.32.amzn1
Size        : 238 k
Repo        : amzn-updates/latest
Summary     : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
URL         : http://openjdk.java.net/
License     : ASL 1.1 and ASL 2.0 and GPL+ and GPLv2 and GPLv2 with exceptions and LGPL+ and LGPLv2 and MPLv1.0 and
            : MPLv1.1 and Public Domain and W3C
Description : The OpenJDK runtime environment.
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。java version "1.8.0_131" はインストール済みなのですがパッチが当たったVersion     : 1.8.0.141 にアップデートできなくて悩んでおります。